# Why is character "A" used in select instead of "*"?

Tags: sql, grails, groovy

In a groovy application the query contains just a letter in the select.

Example:
SELECT a
FROM Employee a
WHERE a.emplID =123456

My question is that the same as:
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE emplId=123456

If not what is the above query doing?

Comment: "My question is that the same as: SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE emplId=123456" - It is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` in this case is an alias to the `Employee` table.

An alias is declared in the `FROM` statement, then referenced in the `SELECT` statement.

```sql
SELECT a
FROM Employee a
```

This is basically the same as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Employee
```

If you want to reference specific columns when using an alias, it would be done like this:

```sql
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, a.Salary
FROM Employee a
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In your example **a** represents the Employee data, and is the same as saying **Employee.***. So, yes it's the same as selecting all the data being returned by that query.